# How to compile Solidity code in the browser?

Tags: solidity, remix, solcjs

I am building a tool to deploy solidity contracts using pre-made templates.

I want to compile solidity (like [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/)) so I can deploy it directly from the client-side (I do not want to use a server).

I have tried using [browser-solc](https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc) and looked at [remix-solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/tree/master/libs/remix-solidity) but have not figured out a straightforward way to compile Solidity in the browser. Any help would be really appreciated!

Related questions:

- [4 years, 1 month ago] [Easiest way to compile solidity in user's browser?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29787/easiest-way-to-compile-solidity-in-users-browser)
- [3 years, 3 months ago] [How to compile solidity in the browser without using browser-solc?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58434/how-to-compile-solidity-in-the-browser-without-using-browser-solc)

Answer (score 3):

[browser-solc](https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc) is a bit out-dated and doesn't work with the latest compiler versions. I updated the [browser-solc](https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc) code so it works with newer compiler versions.
Source code: https://pastebin.com/QxEz6tQU

Copy/ paste the code into a file named: `browser-solc-min.js`

Import the file into your webpage and you will be able to use the compiler by following the [browser-solc tutorial](https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc).

For a list of supported compilers check: [List](https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/list.js)

Or try out my example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span>Input:</span><br>
        <textarea id="input" cols="60" rows="8"> </textarea><br>
        <button id="compile">Compile</button><br>
        <span>Output:</span><br>
        <textarea id="output"></textarea>

        <script src="./browser-solc-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script>
            let contractCode = `
            contract Test {
                uint256 public number = 2;

                function changeNumber(uint256 _number) external {
                    number = _number;
                }
            }
            `;

            const solidityVersion = "soljson-v0.8.10+commit.fc410830.js";

            document.getElementById("compile").addEventListener("click", () => {
                let sourceCode = {
                    language: "Solidity",
                    sources: { 
                        contract: {
                            content: document.getElementById("input").value
                        }
                    },
                    settings: {
                        optimizer: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        evmVersion: "istanbul",
                        outputSelection: {
                            "*": {
                            "": [
                                "legacyAST",
                                "ast"
                            ],
                            "*": [
                                "abi",
                                "evm.bytecode.object",
                                "evm.bytecode.sourceMap",
                                "evm.deployedBytecode.object",
                                "evm.deployedBytecode.sourceMap",
                                "evm.gasEstimates"
                            ]
                            },
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Compiling the contract
                let result = compiler.compile(JSON.stringify(sourceCode), 1);

                // Displaying the result
                document.getElementById("output").value = JSON.stringify(result);
            });

            window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
                document.getElementById("input").value = contractCode;

                // Loading compiler
                BrowserSolc.loadVersion(solidityVersion, function(c) {
                    compiler = c;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Loading the compiler (`BrowserSolc.loadVersion ...`) leads to the following error on the console: "_Uncaught RangeError: WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.compile, or compile on a worker thread._" I was getting the same error on my fork of `browser-solc`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
You can use [@agnostico/browser-solidity-compiler](https://github.com/rexdavinci/browser-solidity-compiler). It works in ReactJS and has typescript support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks the official [ethereum/solc-js](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) compiler works in browsers now ([Ref](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#browser-usage))

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://binaries.soliditylang.org/bin/{{ SOLC VERSION }}.js"
></script>
```